# Hyperledger fabric: unexpected deliverResponse status received - 404

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am facing an issue with calling chaincode to store asset after pushing few 100 records. I am getting an error in my node application logs.

```
2021-03-08T10:04:09.498Z - error: [EventService]: on.data [peer1.org1.example.com,peer1.org1.example.com] - #11- unexpected deliverResponse status received - 404
```

If I restart the node application, it starts working again for storing few 100 records and then the same issue comes back. I try to search in google regarding this, but I couldn´t find any helpful resource. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the clock of your system.
I you are on Ubuntu use

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp off
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```